# GPO block USB write access to all users with exceptions

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-10

I would Like to block write access to removable drives for all users but allow some users to have access to write on the USB.

This is what I have done.

1. Created new security Group "Enable_USB_Access"
2. Created New Policy and Deny Access "\User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\System\Removable Storage Access"

[image: GPMC view of Removable Storage Access settings]

On Delegation Tab I added security Group "Enable_USB_Access" and denied Apply Policy

But when I login with any user I can write to USB/CD.

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Run `gpresult /h gpresult.html` and confirm the settings, your group membership, and the GPO appear in the report.

Comment: When I run GPresult. I can see these settings are being applied